# Find all black rectangles in an image - imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

How do you find black rectangles (of varying pixel colors, mostly black, but due to photography aberrations could be other), in an image?

Comment: Post an example. Possibly threshold and use connected components.

Comment: Please be more specific if you would like assistance. As it stands, it's hard to know what you mean. Ultimately a single black pixel is a rectangle. A 1920x1080 white image with a 1 pixel wide border around it might be what you are looking for.